# Woocommerce | display different text on product page if product has tag "xyz"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to put a text or html under the short product description
Normally I can put any text in the **short-description.php** file
But I want this text to be displayed only when my product has a Special tag and also the user is not registered

For example, when my product has a "**Free**" tag, show the user the following text in short description

Please register to purchase the product for free
And when the user is registered, do not show the text to him

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_text_after_excerpt_single_product( $short_description ) {
    global $product;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_tag' );

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        if ( $term->name == 'Free' && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $short_description .= 'Please register to purchase the product for free';
        }

    }

    return $short_description;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description','add_text_after_excerpt_single_product', 20, 1);
```